# Open local server's page on Android Chrome

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, android-chrome

I'm trying to access a website on my local server from my Android cellphone.
Following [this google tutorial](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/local-server).

- Chrome DevTools detects my device
- i set Port Forwarding rule `localhost:5000 -> localhost:8000`

But i can't get it to work...
When i access localhost:5000, the browser renders **This site can't be reached**.

I also tried `127.0.0.1:5000`

I researched a lot and couldn't find any solution.

Is this a conection problem?

Comment: If you have port forwarded, you should be accessing the forwarded port from your external IP: http://www.whatsmyip.org; not your internal IP which is what `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` usually are.

Comment: @zero298 The [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/local-server) teaches you to access the website through `localhost`, not depending on any network configuration (all the traffic going through USB cable). So i should be able to access through `localhost:5000`, which will be maped to `localhost:8000` on my local development machine, but somehow i can't get it to work

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I misunderstood.  I didn't read your link and thought that you were trying to do something else.  However, for clarity, where are you  trying to navigate to the forwarded address, your mobile or your desktop?

Comment: Additionally what port do you usually use to access your site?  Is it mapped to in your tools or are you just using `5000` from the tutorial?

Comment: @zero298 I'm trying to navigate to the forwarded address from my cellphone, to the website that's being served by my laptop server. Usually i serve on port 8000 on my local Webpack development server, the tutorial says i can navigate (on my cellphone) to `localhost:5000` and get the content being served in my laptop's `localhost:8000`

Comment: It works now, but i did nothing lol...thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

try using http://localhost:8080/ [the number can be your port number] worked for me.